# Using a namespace twice

Tags: c++, namespaces

In c++ Is it OK to include same namespace twice?
compiler wont give any error but still will it affect in anyway

Thanks,

**EDIT:**
I meant

```
using namespace std;

// . . STUFF
using namespace std;
```

Comment: please clarify "include same namespace twice". Are you asking if it's ok to declare "using somenamespace; using somenamespace;" or are you asking if it's ok to declare a namespace mutliple times, as in "namespace SomeNamespace {} namespace SomeNamespace {}"?

Comment: I meant

using namespace std;
.
.
using namespace std;

Comment: I know adding same line twice would be dumb. 
but if "using namespace std" is done two different header files and both are in included in .cpp file will there be any problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends what you mean by 'include'. Saying:

```
using namespace std;    
...    
using namespace std:
```

is OK. But saying:

```
namespace X {
   ...
namespace X {
```

would create a nested namespace called X::X, which is probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 8):

This usage is fine, if it's what your talking about:

**File: foo.h**

```
namespace tools
{
  class Widget
  {
  ...
  };
}
```

**file: bar.h**

```
namespace tools
{
  class Gizmo
  {
  ...
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Twice in the same class/file? It shouldn't be a problem, but neither should it be necessary. I'd naively assume that you should be able to refactor your code to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean. You can put multiple classes in a single namespace (that's the whole idea). Each class generally has it's own files, so yes, you can use the same namespace in multiple files.

Though not technically required, it's a good idea to have a directory structure that represents the namespace hierarchy you create.

As for for the *using* directive: the compiler and/or intellisense most likely gives you a warning (the C# one does), but otherwise there is no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking whether following is okay ?

```
using namespace std;
using namespace std;
```

It is okay but normally I prefer to refer the namespace element with scope resolution.

ex:

```
std::vector
std::sort
```