# Including namespace multiple times

Tags: c++, c++11

Will there be a problem if the same namespace is included multiple times?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace custom;
using namespace custom;
```

Can it be possible to apply guard to namespace like header files so that namespace won't be included more than once? (Like #ifndef ...)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001154/using-a-namespace-twice

Comment: It is bad practice to have a using directive in a header.  That will poison any source files that `#include` it.  The guard against this is to never have using directives in your header files!

Comment: I haven't specified anywhere I included namespace in header file.

Comment: Then how is the namespace declaration in danger of getting included more than once?  It sounds like you're up to 10 kinds of no good here.  Also, it goes without saying that files that are meant for inclusion are referred to as headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference between namespace directives and preprocessor directives. You can write it twice, but that won't get you anywhere.

Secondly, there is no way to guard "against" this as it is not a problem. Namespace directives do not need to be guarded, nor repeated.

This post conveys a bit of where errors may arise in regards to namespace. Apologies if this information is extraneous - just trying to provide clarity.

[Pintu Shukla's post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/ce4727e7-15f4-4731-86bf-e6451175af9d/) --

> NameSpace is just a Declerative Region of your code or your variable.it is used to avoid collision between variable or function name etc have a look on the Following Code.
>
> this is a valid code

```
namespace st
{
int i =0;
}
namespace st
{
 int j =0;
}

using namespace st;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
i=15;
j =10;
cout<<i<<j;
return 0;
}
```

> now try this.this code will give you a error that 'i' : redefinition
>   and multiple initialization
>
> Code Block

```
namespace st
{
int i = 0
}

namespace st
{
int i =0;
}

using namespace st;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
i=15;
cout<<i;

return 0;

}
```

> So if you have declared two namespace with same name that is properly
>   valid . but if both namespace contain same object it will throw error
>   .

Answer (score 5):

It's a good practice NOT to use "using namespace" in headers.

Comment: Yes, just to add some explanation: anyone who wants to use your class is then forced to also use your namespace!

Comment: Even-though this a good practice, there is absolutely no evidence that OP is doing this.

Comment: My guess would be an assumption because this is the only sensible scenario that results in the same namespace declaration occuring multiple times, as surely nobody is silly enough to write it in the same C++ file.

Comment: I'm not including namespace in header file. Its included in cpp.

Comment: In this case, there is no reason to do, or not do this.  It is doing no evil, beyond the 20 wasted bytes on your hard drive, which, unless this is pushing you over a block for this given file, is likely boiled down to nothing anyway.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem if you have multiple namespace directives. It has the same effect.
Written once or multiple times a using namespace directive imports all the symbols from the namespace in to the current namespace.

Comment: Can the list of imported names change between the two occurrences, so the second adds some more information?  Or if you have `using namespace std;` before you have any `std` symbols, do the symbols that appear subsequently get 'automatically' imported too?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: No and No.

Comment: Any symbols that exist within that namespace would have to exist at compile time, otherwise any objects wouldn't link properly.